# How do I make a disabled compose OutlinedTextField look like its enabled?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a compose OutlinedTextField which shouldn't be manually editable but filled using input from something that happens on clicking the text field. But setting the field as `readOnly=true` makes the `clickable` modifier not work. So a workaround I found is to set it as `enabled=false` which lets clickable work.

```
OutlinedTextField(
    value = text,
    onValueChange = { text = it},
    enabled = false,
    modifier = Modifier.clickable { text= "Clicked"}
)
```

How can I make this look as if its enabled based on whatever theme is being followed without setting a fixed color?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `TextFieldDefaults.outlinedTextFieldColors` applying in the disabled colors the same value of the enabled colors without using hardcoded values:

```
OutlinedTextField(
    //...
    enabled = false,
    colors = TextFieldDefaults.outlinedTextFieldColors(
        disabledTextColor = LocalContentColor.current.copy(LocalContentAlpha.current),
        backgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
        disabledBorderColor = MaterialTheme.colors.onSurface.copy(alpha = ContentAlpha.disabled),
        disabledLabelColor = MaterialTheme.colors.onSurface.copy(ContentAlpha.medium),
    )
)
```

Comment: Thank you, this works well and looks good. This is the only way I managed to make an OutlinedTextField clickable.

Comment: doesn't work on M3

Answer (score 5):

The accepted solution is deprecated.

> Deprecated: Renamed to `OutlinedTextFieldDefaults.colors` with additional
> parameters to control container color based on state.

The current alternative would be:

```
OutlinedTextField(
    //...
    enabled = false,
    colors = OutlinedTextFieldDefaults.colors(
        disabledTextColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSurface,
        disabledContainerColor = Color.Transparent,
        disabledBorderColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.outline,
        disabledLeadingIconColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSurfaceVariant,
        disabledTrailingIconColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSurface,
        disabledLabelColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSurfaceVariant,
        disabledPlaceholderColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSurfaceVariant,
        disabledSupportingTextColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSurfaceVariant,
        disabledPrefixColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSurfaceVariant,
        disabledSuffixColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSurfaceVariant
    ),
```

Comment: Actually this won't work to use the default values, only the readOnly will give the proper M3 values and disallow the input.

Answer (score 1):

I should suggest just , add the parameter

```
readOnly = true
```

It will behave same but it is clickable.